# Google Analyze visits of images in a gallery without url. (modal)

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I would like to tag a "Button" that makes each image in the gallery visible to me. Each image will have a different tag which will then be displayed in analytic events.
I think this is the only way to be able to analyze gallery visits without a url.

```html
<a onclick="document.getElementById('id001').style.display='block'" class="item-link">
          <img class="miniatur" src="img001"/></a>
```

The tag I believe is of type:

?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=campaignname&utm_content=adsetname--adname

But where do I write it?

Comment: Unfortunately on my phone with the tiny fonts I didn't notice the error in the title. I think the question is clear though. I have no possibility to edit.